# How to increase hard disk on VM Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine

I'm trying increase the Hard disk size on the VM Virtual Machine to 74GB as shown in the image. However the hard disk size won't increase - it stays at 64GB.

Can someone let me know how to go about increasing the hard disk successfully?

[image: VMMachine]
[image: VMMachine]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing the hard disk inside the hypervisor is only the first step.  You will also have to expand the disk within the operating system.

I see that you are using a Windows guest OS, so to do so open up a run prompt and enter diskmgmt.msc.  Once inside the disk management interface, right click the partition you want to expand and select extend volume.